# REST exception needs constructor

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jakarta-ee

I have a rest web service, It returns objects from a class `FoodItem` which doesn't have public empty constructor. However, It contains another constructors which aren't empty parameters.

I got this exception

```
May 15, 2013 11:06:50 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse logException
SEVERE: Mapped exception to response: 500 (Internal Server Error)
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
com.mypackage.eattel.food.FoodItemImpl does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.mypackage.eattel.food.FoodItemImpl

    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractRootElementProvider.writeTo(AbstractRootElementProvider.java:159)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:306)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1479)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
com.mypackage.eattel.food.FoodItemImpl does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.mypackage.eattel.food.FoodItemImpl

    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.getStoredJAXBContext(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:194)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.getJAXBContext(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:187)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.getMarshaller(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:165)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.getMarshaller(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:144)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractRootElementProvider.writeTo(AbstractRootElementProvider.java:151)
    ... 24 more
```

when I make public empty parameter constructor in my `FoodItem` class, the exception solved and I got the exact results.

**My question:**
How to solve that exception without adding empty constructor?, It is impossible in my business logic to have empty constructor.

Thanks in advance

**Edit**
My class implements an Interface, Maybe this information could help you.

**Edit2**
If you want the code for my `web.xml`, my classes, my interfaces or my webservice I am ready

**Edit3**

This is the code in the web service

```
@GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public FoodItem getRestarantsFordBrowser() {
        return FoodItemImpl.getInstance(1);
    }
```

so as you see, I am calling Static method.

The code of the static method is:

```
public static FoodItem getInstance(int ID) {
        return new FoodItemImpl(ID);
    }
```

**and this constructor is PRIVATE, so I don't need a public constructor to create objects and in my web service I am calling method static so I don't have to create object explicity.**

Comment: Is the constructor with argument calling no-arg constructor ?

Comment: @Santosh no no, it is not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, if you don't write a constructor, default constructor will be added by the java run time and instances will be initialized with default values. But if you add a constructor in your class then JVM does not add the default constructor and you should add the default constructor. The reason behind, why JVM adds a default constructor when there is no construcor defined is that, if it does not then you will not be able to create an object of that class. But if you have added a constructor, then JVM assumes that you have one and using that one you should be able to create objects.

Comment: I don't have to use public constructor to create an object, check my edit please

Comment: Your REST server is trying to instantiate FoodItemImpl with no argument constructor and as you have not added in your class so it is complining.

Comment: why does the REST trying to instantiate a new object from `FoodItemImpl` ????? I didn't request that

Answer (score 0):

This is typical use of reflection in `Java` and it's being followed by many other frameworks as well which uses reflection to construct objects.

This is how in general POJO or Java beans are constructed (default):

> Call default empty constructor of an class, it must be `public`
>
> Call setters on available fields to set field values

Springs allows various ways to construct objects, in your case you can try using Jersey+Spring for using constructor with parameter approach.

Comment: I don't have to use public constructor to create an object, check my edit please